# Does the gravitational wave community plan to lower the threshold for claiming detections by 2000x?

Tags: gravitational-waves, statistics

I've read:

> To investigate the impact of reducing the parameter space for GRB
>   searches, we will deliberately avoid the question of first
>   gravitational wave detection - where a "5-sigma" observation may well
>   be required (Abadie et al. 2012c). Instead, we consider a later
>   observation for which we might require a specific false positive rate:
>   i.e. a limit on the fraction gravitational wave observations are
>   spurious. In that case, the threshold for announcing a detection is
>   tied to the true signal rate.
>   [...]
>   When the advanced LIGO and
>   Virgo detectors are operating at design sensitivity, the expected
>   rate of observed BNS mergers is 20 per year. Thus the threshold corresponds to a false positive rate of 1 in 2000.

http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8149

My understanding is that where
$$
FAR=\text{False Alarm Rate}\\
FAP=\text{False Alarm Probability}\\
TSR=\text{True Signal Rate}\\
FPR=\text{False Positive Rate}\\
t=\text{Search Time}
$$

**R code:**

```
FAR=1/100 #yr^-1 
TSR=20 #yr^-1
t=16/365 #yr

FAP=1-exp(-FAR*t)
Nsigma=qnorm(1-FAP)
FPR=FAR/(FAR+TSR)
```

**Results:**

```
> FAP
[1] 0.0004382601
> Nsigma
[1] 3.327427
> FPR
[1] 0.0004997501
> 1/FPR
[1] 2001
```

So it appears the plan is to lower the FAR threshold to $1/100~yr^{-1}$, which would correspond to a $3.3\sigma$ observation. To get a threshold of $5\sigma$, just change to $FAR=\frac{1}{200,000}~yr^{-1}$. This assumes a typical search time of $\frac{16}{365}~yr$, which was the case for GW150914. We could instead consider a longer search time of $1~yr$ or shorter of $\frac{1}{365}~yr$, which would correspond to $2.3\sigma$ and $4.0\sigma$ observations, respectively.

Is this really the plan? If so, what is the reasoning here? I can (somewhat) understand not bothering to report the estimated false positive rate when the TSR is extremely uncertain, but not why the threshold for detection should also become more lenient.

Comment: The cited paper seems to be discussing a particular search event: finding GRBs (gamma ray bursters) via gravitational waves.  The LIGO news release says that the recent detection was 5.1 sigma.

Comment: @PeterDiehr I agree the focus of the paper is on a different type of event than GW150914, the calculation is also for neutron stars rather than black holes. However, there is nothing in the calculation referring to GrBs, and I've seen this threshold used elsewhere as well. For example, when [estimating detector sensitivity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03842) the same is used: *"We impose a nominal one-per-century threshold on the FAR"*. Anyway, the answer may very well be "No, that is not the plan".

Comment: GW150914 was, as far as I can tell, far larger than a $5\sigma$ event. This is about the  gamma and x-ray signal detection being the primary signal that triggers an after-the-fact search for a very weak gravitational signal that normally wouldn't even make the LIGO cuts. The opposite scenario, which they are not interested in is that LIGO may find a gravitational signal that then triggers a search for the gamma signals. I am not sure that's even possible. The satellites are usually not equipped to store data that doesn't pass the triggers. That data is simply lost in space.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks, that would make sense. So this calculation is just an example of what would make them look closer at a signal rather than *"the threshold for announcing a detection"*. Regarding the latter, I don't think the actual sigma-level for a given event is relevant to error rates, since any signal passing the threshold would be announced.

Comment: The idea is that you take a clean trigger from the gamma satellites and then use that to search for a gravitational signal that is too weak to make the cut all by itself. It's a combined analysis with complicated biases, so I don't think a simple Gaussian analysis comes even close to getting the correct results for the significance and false detection rate. I am always skeptical when detector data is being analyzed "the easy" way. It's a little bit like armchair coaching...

Comment: @CuriousOne "*It's a combined analysis with complicated biases, so I don't think a simple Gaussian analysis comes even close to getting the correct results for the significance and false detection rate."* My understanding was that these complications are all considered upstream, ie in estimating FAR and TSR. For GW150914 they definitely did not assume detector noise was Gaussian, but still use the calculations above to describe the finding in different ways.

Comment: One can always make simplifying assumptions... the question is whether they are actually valid. I rather rely on Monte Carlo analyses than on statistical estimations that may, or may not, be correct.

Comment: @CuriousOne That is what was done. To estimate FAR, they used a rather involved [Monte Carlo time-shift procedure](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102): *"Estimating this background is challenging for two reasons: the detector noise is nonstationary and non-Gaussian, so its properties must be empirically determined"*. To get FAP and Nsigma from FAR, they seem to have used the simple calculations above (which give the reported values). So I do believe my question contains the calculations actually used in practice. It's not clear whether you are saying this is incorrect.

Comment: That is kind of what I was trying to say. If the noise is non-Gaussian, then one has to do the Monte-Carlo individually for a change of parameters, does one not? Having said that, your estimation may have the right order of magnitude, anyway.